# 32Feet - Discover only devices in range

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

Is there any way of discovering all devices that are currently in range using 32Feet?

I tried

```
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] allDevicesInRange = client.DiscoverDevices(255, false, false, true);
```

This returns all *unknown* devices in range. Once I've paired with my device, if I try this again, it won't find the device again (because it's not unknown any more).  I have to go into the Bluetooth Devices applet in Windows and remove it before this will find it again.

I have also tried both

```
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] allDevicesInRange = client.DiscoverDevices(255, false, true, true);
```

and

```
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] allDevicesInRange = client.DiscoverDevices(255, true, false, true);
```

In this case it does find my device every time, but now it finds them even when the device is switched off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] DiscoverDevices(int maxDevices, bool authenticated, bool remembered, bool unknown, bool discoverableOnly);
```

You are going to have to do it in two parts

1. Discover all authenticated devices, i.e. one's you have and are paired to, then manually try to connect to each one in turn, to test whether or not it is in range.
2. Discover all devices that are not authenticated (this will return only devices present and in range, that you have not / are not paired to)